# Latex : Understand memoir pagestyle

Tags: latex, memoir

I have a sample of doc in latex and would like you to explain why this is not working as expected.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{background}

\begin{document}
\SetBgContents{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{header test}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

After compilation:

1. Indentation of the page changes from page to page
2. "header test" some time appears, sometime not
3. There are blank pages when I explicitly put "clearpage"

Can you please explain how to solve and make something stable ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unless specified otherwise, the default option passed to [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) is to set the document in `twoside` mode. See p 5 of the [`memoir` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) under REMARKS:

   > Calling the class with no options is equivalent to:
   >
   > ```
   > \documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final]{memoir}
   > ```

   Under `twoside`, the odd and even pages are offset from the inner margin, or the gutter. This results in the differing "indentations" of the page.
2. `\makeoddhead` only sets the `head`er for `odd` pages. Odd pages only occur every *other* page, leaving `even` page headers empty (the default for the `plain` page style).
3. `\clearpage` flushes all pending floats and starts a new page. There should be no blank page issued. However, with a call to `\chapter`, `memoir` actually issues `\clearforchapter`, which is similar to `\cleartorecto` or `\cleardoublepage`. This necessarily clears pages until an odd page is reached, ensuring that a chapter starts on a right.